# how to open a jquery-ui dialog from included page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a problem using **jquery-ui dialog** with **php**. I'm begginer to jquery. I tried to solve it my self but I couldn't.
I have "**index.php**" as home page to my website:
**index.php:**

```
<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "includes/config.php"; ?>

<?php include "includes/right_side_bar.php"; ?>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ajax.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I referenced all the related jquery-ui scripts, also the style sheets (which are exists in the "**header.php**").

in the **index.php** I included "**right_side_bar.php**", which has a **button** that call **jquery-ui**:
**right_side_bar.php:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/general.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqueryui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/validation.js"></script>                 
<div class="right_sidebar"> 
    <div class="single_widget">
        <h2 id="welcomeLogin">Login Page</h2>      
        <form id="loginForm" action="" method="post">    
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a id="clickform" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">login</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>          
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what I need when I click on that **button** which exists in "**right_side_bar.php**" is to make **jquery-ui** fires and create the dialog
**validation.js:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").hide();
    $("#clickform").click(function(){     
        $("#container").load("includes/update_user_info.php #customForm",function(rt,ts,xhr){
            if(ts == "error")
                alert("ERROR!!!!!!");
            else
                alert("Success!!");
        });
        alert("Done..!!");
        $("#container").attr('title','Registration Form').dialog({width:600, height:600, closeOnEscape: true, draggable: true, resizable: false, show:'fade',modal:true});
    });
});
```

the "**#container**" is a "**div**" tag which exists in the main page (**index.php**), this "**div**" will hold the `form` tag that came from "**update_user_info.php**".

when I run the code everything works fine, even the `alerts` are displayed, but the "**jquery-ui dialog**" never displayed.

I forgot to mention that I made "**index2.php**" and copied the "**right_side_bar.php**" into "**index2.php**" (I mean without including it) and the dialog works correctly without any problem. but I need that code to be included.

I know I wrote very much, but I want you to guide me if I made something wrong with this code.

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the resulting HTML. This is what your jQuery will be interacting with ion the end, so it's whats important. Also, do you see any errors or info in your JS Console when you load the page or attempt to launch the Dialog?

Comment: Also, I see that `#container` is hidden, but then is never shown. You may want to add `$("#container").show()` at some point when you're ready to show the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that pops out at me is that you have jquery-ui included twice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You should only include it once, I would recommend you use the jquery-ui.min.js minified version only as it is a smaller payload, and remove jquery-ui.js.

Other than that are you seeing any errors in your console?

Alternatively if you need an external jquery-ui to verify you can try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I deleted the first included script, but nothing changed.
also, I looked at the console as you suggest, and found this **error**:
**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).dialog is not a function**

(anonymous function)   @ validation.js:11
dispatch                        @ jquery.min.js:3r.
handle                           @ jquery.min.js:3
..** Do you have any idea what this means?!!**

Comment: This most likely means that jquery ui isnt actually included on your page, so either the link to jquery ui is wrong or the file doesnt even exist. You can try using this to test:<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I added the code to my original post since it doesnt seem to work in comments.

Comment: thanks man it works. on last question: what is the difference between the external jquery-ui and the local ones?!! doesn't this thing slowing the load of the page?!! thanks again..

Comment: Actually, typically that would improve your loading speed since it's delivered from a Google CDN. If you want to have a local copy then just download it to your file structure and include it from there.

As for the difference, the external one is hosted by Google and an internal one would be in your own file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/km3zx1pt/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#container").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    show: 'fade',
    modal: true
  });
  $("#clickform").click(function() {
    // Example Code to test loading HTML content from remote source
    // Replace with .load() and your own URL
    $.post("/echo/html/", {
        html: "<h2>ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US.</h2>"
      },
      function(d) {
        $("#container").html(d);
        $("#container").dialog("option", "title", 'Registration Form')
          .dialog("open");
      });
  });
});
```

In this way, we initialize the dialog with all our settings up front. We collect the Form data or HTML and add it to the Dialog container. We then update the title and open the dialog for viewing.

It all appears to work here, but I do not have all the extra scripts you're eluding to in your post. There could be a conflict.